# Connection to SQL Server in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, sql-server, database

I want to add database connection to SQL Server from ArcMap.

But, I don't know what to write as 'instance'. I've tried 'NT Service\MSSQLSERVER' but it doesn't work.

[image]

Comment: Worth searching the ESRI knowledge base articles, I found [this](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000005044)?

Comment: @Hornbydd It says 'Failure to access the DBMS server'

Comment: Once all connections were Direct Connect, the "sde:rdbmskey:" was eliminated in favor of a picklist and an RDBMS-dependent parameter string.

Comment: [Here](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/gdbs-in-sql-server/connect-sqlserver.htm) is the doc for your specific question. There's syntax instructions and an image example.

Answer (score 2):

If you installed SQL server with default instance on your computer, then just write ".\". It means localhost.

You can find instance name from services in windows:

Go to windows services => find SQL Server.The default instance name is **MSSQLSERVER**.

Other instance names also are between parentheses.

[image]

[image]

If SQL server installed on a server and you want to connect to this, you should use server IP (You may need a VPN). 
In the below image you can see an IP and an instance name (not default instance).You maybe need to use a port for connecting to a server like this:
**(192.0.0.0:2222\instancename)**

[image]

Comment: I installed with default instance on my computer. I tried the first choice you mentioned, it says 'The user's default database is a system database; automatic connections to system databases are not allowed. Please provide a different database for connection.'

Comment: Try to connect with "sa" user or windows authentication.

Comment: @fatmasen How to get the "sa" password?

Answer (score 0):

I my connections to SQL Server I put the server IP address or the server name in the Instance parameter, but I'm using Database Authentication as Authentication Type.

Comment: It's not quite just server name or IP -- If it's a *named instance*, then that custom instance name would be appended, with a backslash between them.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it depends on how the servers/instances are set up. Check with whoever has control on that. At our place we use server name along the lines of this:

[image: Database COnnction dialog]

The database instance, databases and users are set up by out IT contractor.